# How can I put the last zsh command in history into a clipboard?

Tags: bash, shell, history, zsh

It often happens to me, that I just used a command and I need to copy/paste it either to a different terminal window/IM or whatever.

On a Mac, I can use the `pbcopy` command to get something in clipboard, but I'm not sure how should I get to the command. What I've came up is

```
history | tail -n 1 | perl -ple 's/\d+\s+//' | pbcopy
```

which works, but it doesn't really seem like clean solution. Is there a better way to get to the last command? I'm using `zsh`, but I guess if there's a solution for `bash` it will work in `zsh` too.

Answer (score 8):

As a one-off for the last command:

```
echo !! | pbcopy
```

will put exactly the last command into the clipboard.

Comment: This is a very nice trick! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use xclip for this task
See [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip)
Your can just pipe something into the clipboard like this:

```
history 2 | xclip
```

Comment: xclip requires a X11 session...

Comment: If you read the question carefully, you will notice this part of the first sentence: "I need to copy/paste it either to a different terminal window/IM or whatever.". Doesn't that imply that he has a X Session?

Comment: No, it implies he has a window session, which may be X, but it also may be unity, NeWS, Finder.app or any of the other gui interfaces one may have to a system.